# Power BI - How to filtered cards without changing other diagramms & cards

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

iam new at power bi and its a great tool. :)

But now i have a new Tasks about showing datas with barchart, card,..

[image: dasbhoard]

So my Bar chart is filterd by years and it works fine but now i want the same for cards.

For example i need: cards under the year 2017 -> filterd 2017 **without changing** other bar charts and cards and the same for cards 2018 & 2019 **witout changing** other cards.

How i can solve that exactly?

Kind regards,

Unknown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select your bar chart of 2017 and then go to the Format Tab -> Edit Interactions. Edit Interaction feature allows you to handle filtering of data. So select your chart of 2017 and then click on no filter icon(None) of other charts for which you don't want to filter data on the click of that chart.

Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-reports-visual-interactions) for more info.